# htaccess redirect with folder name

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with htaccess redirects. Out site was wrongly crawled by google and as a result there are a lot of wrong urls being shown in webmaster tool. As an example:

articles/abcd/xyz 
should be redirected as
articles/abcd/

articles/abcd/xyz.php
should be redirected as
articles/abcd/

articles/abcd/xyz.html
should be redirected as
articles/abcd/

So basically I am trying to mean always redirect to articles/abcd/ for varous wrong url types that i shown above. Please could you help

Comment: Your question is awfully vague. Is "xyz" always the same? Is there always one part after "articles"?

Comment: No it will not be, it could be anything else as well. I just wanted to give an example. Let me know if a redirect is possible

Comment: Yes, it probably is possible, but I cannot tell how unless I know what the standard-form is of the url. If there is not always 1 part after the "articles", what other url's do you have that you don't want to redirect?

Comment: The only other form is that it can be articles/. Does this help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `RedirectMatch` from mod_alias ([documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)). We assume that the part after articles does not contain any `/` character. We redirect with a temporary redirect to the url without the suffix. Change "temp" to "permanent" after testing that this redirect actually works as you expect it to work.

```
RedirectMatch temp ^(/articles/[^/]+/).+$ $1
```